# HummusJS - Convert HTML page to PDF in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, hummus.js

How can I use hummusJS to convert HTML code to PDF?
So far I am able to convert JPG images to pdf, as well as merge multiple pdfs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

puppeteer is a good solution:

**Installation**

```
npm i puppeteer
# or "yarn add puppeteer"
```

**Example - create a PDF.**

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('https://news.ycombinator.com', {waitUntil: 'networkidle2'});
  await page.pdf({path: 'hn.pdf', format: 'A4'});

  await browser.close();
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use **html-to-pdf-converter**

Using headless chrome via puppeteer and than modifying generated pdf via **HummusJS** to add headers and footers with page numbers

**Install**

```
npm install html-to-pdf-converter
```

For me node-html-pdf with phantomjs is the best.

**Install**

```
npm install -g html-pdf
```

**code example:**

```
var fs = require('fs');
var pdf = require('html-pdf');
var html = fs.readFileSync('./test/businesscard.html', 'utf8');
var options = { format: 'Letter' };

pdf.create(html, options).toFile('./businesscard.pdf', function(err, res) {
  if (err) return console.log(err);
  console.log(res); // { filename: '/app/businesscard.pdf' }
});
```

Comment: I already tried that. it works. But I wanted to know if this is possible using hummusJS.

Comment: Using a page content context, you can write text. (if you can write text so easy to write html code into pdf )
look at this:
https://github.com/galkahana/HummusJS/wiki/Show-text

Comment: By HTML code I mean HTML parsed code. Just like any website page (and not the actual code).